# Kentico - Web part zone visibility based on Child folder

Tags: kentico

I have a page with a repeater inside a webpart zone to display rotating content (in a carousel). Content for the carousel comes from the /Carousel/ folder, which is a child of the page itself.

What I want to do but don't know how is to set the visibility of the webpart zone based on the presence of the /Carousel/ folder: if the /Carousel/ folder is there -> show the webpart zone/repeater, if not -> hide it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run into this same thing many times, so i actually built a macro specifically for this type of stuff (since as you've commented, the visibility is on the webpart zone and not the repeater).

Here's the macro method

```
            [MacroMethod(typeof(bool), "Finds if at least 1 child exists under the given node for navigation purposes",1 )]
            [MacroMethodParam(0, "int", typeof(int), "The Node ID")]
            [MacroMethodParam(1, "Text", typeof(string), "A list of valid page types, comma, semi-colon, or bar seperated")]
            [MacroMethodParam(2, "bool", typeof(bool), "Include Unpuglished pages (false by default)")]
            [MacroMethodParam(3, "bool", typeof(bool), "Include Documents Hidden from Navigation (false by default)")]
            public static object NodeHasNavigationChildren(EvaluationContext context, params object[] parameters)
            {
                switch (parameters.Length)
                {
                    case 1:
                        return HBS_Gen_Module.GeneralHelpers.NodeHasNavigationChildren(ValidationHelper.GetInteger(parameters[0], -1));
                    case 2:
                        return HBS_Gen_Module.GeneralHelpers.NodeHasNavigationChildren(ValidationHelper.GetInteger(parameters[0], -1), ValidationHelper.GetString(parameters[1], ""));
                    case 3:
                        return HBS_Gen_Module.GeneralHelpers.NodeHasNavigationChildren(ValidationHelper.GetInteger(parameters[0], -1), ValidationHelper.GetString(parameters[1], ""), ValidationHelper.GetBoolean(parameters[2], false));
                    case 4:
                        return HBS_Gen_Module.GeneralHelpers.NodeHasNavigationChildren(ValidationHelper.GetInteger(parameters[0], -1), ValidationHelper.GetString(parameters[1], ""), ValidationHelper.GetBoolean(parameters[2], false), ValidationHelper.GetBoolean(parameters[3], false));
                    default:
                    case 0:
                        throw new NotSupportedException();
                }
            }
```

And here's the actual method it calls:

```
/// <summary>
        /// Checks if there exists a Node that should be displayed in navigation, this is more advanced than the "NodeHasChildren" which only checks for published children, and doesn't have page type and DocumentHiddenInNavigation checks
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="NodeID">The Node ID</param>
        /// <param name="PageTypes">Semi-colon, bar, or comma seperated list of class names</param>
        /// <param name="IncludeUnpublished">If unpublished should be included (default false)</param>
        /// <param name="IncludeHiddenNavigationDocuments">If Documents hidden from navigation should be included (default false)</param>
        /// <returns>If there exists at least 1 child that fits</returns>
        public static bool NodeHasNavigationChildren(int NodeID, string PageTypes = "", bool IncludeUnpublished = false, bool IncludeHiddenNavigationDocuments = false)
        {
            return CacheHelper.Cache(cs => NodeHasNavigationChildrenCache(cs, NodeID, PageTypes, IncludeUnpublished, IncludeHiddenNavigationDocuments), new CacheSettings(1440, new string[] { "NodeHasNavigationChildren", NodeID.ToString(), PageTypes, IncludeUnpublished.ToString(), IncludeHiddenNavigationDocuments.ToString() }));
        }
        private static bool NodeHasNavigationChildrenCache(CacheSettings cs, int NodeID, string PageTypes = "", bool IncludeUnpublished = true, bool IncludeHiddenNavigationDocuments = false)
        {
            var ChildQuery = DocumentHelper.GetDocuments().WhereEquals("NodeParentID", NodeID).Columns("NodeID").TopN(1);
            if (IncludeUnpublished)
            {
                ChildQuery.Published(false);
            }

            if (IncludeHiddenNavigationDocuments)
            {
                ChildQuery.Where("DocumentMenuItemHideInNavigation = 0 or DocumentMenuItemHideInNavigation = 1");
            }
            else
            {
                ChildQuery.WhereEquals("DocumentMenuItemHideInNavigation", false);
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(PageTypes))
            {
                ChildQuery.WhereIn("ClassName", PageTypes.Split(";|,".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
            }

            if(cs.Cached)
            {
                TreeNode ParentNode = DocumentHelper.GetDocuments().WhereEquals("NodeID", NodeID).Published(false).FirstObject;
                if(ParentNode != null) {
                    cs.CacheDependency = CacheHelper.GetCacheDependency("node|"+SiteContext.CurrentSiteName+"|" + ParentNode.NodeAliasPath + "|childnodes");
                }
            }

            return ChildQuery.Count > 0;
        }
```

Comment: I think I may get somewhere with this: make the Carousel folder the last child of the page, then add this macro to visibility:
{%CurrentDocument.Children.LastItem.GetValue("DocumentName").Contains("Carousel")#%}  The thing I don't understand is if I move the Carousel up -> it's no longer the last child -> I expect the content stops showing; however, it didn't work as expected.

Comment: That's a pretty hacky way of doing it and can easily lead to problems if the order gets changed, I wouldn't recommend it, not good practice and I've seen content blow up from things like that (like a beginning tag in one web part and an end tag in another, the other gets moved and now you don't have an end tag and the site messes up). Use the custom macro, it will do what you want.

Comment: If you really want to go that route though, the reason it didn't work is you need to set an order so it orders by the node order. Otherwise it's just any children.

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to hide the repeater just set the "No data behavior" property of the repeater to hide if nothing is found.

[image: hide if no data found]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My mistake when mentioning the 'Repeater' instead of the 'Web part zone'. By default, the Repeater has the 'Hide if no record found' checkbox checked. The reason hiding the repeater is not enough because the Webpart zone outside the repeater has a gray background, without the repeater, the gray box is still there. I want to hide the gray box (the webpart zone) if the Carousel folder is not present. Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to implement any custom macro method. You can simply leverage Kentico's default methods like **Exists** in this case:

```
{% CurrentDocument.Children.Exists("DocumentName==\"Carousel\"") %}
```